# C# Correctly anticipating the true height of a string for printing

Tags: c#, printing, fonts

My data isn't fitting the page properly and when I dig into it I find the system is giving me two different numbers:

From the font I find the height listed as 17.  When I actually measure a string I find the height is 18.5, though.  Obviously, the former fits more data on the paper than the latter.  How can I get an accurate estimate of how big the lines really will be short of going through the data and measuring it?  I'm trying to get correct values for page ## of ## on what can be a pretty long printout.

Comment: How are you getting the actual measurement?

Comment: Why not count lines or page breaks?

Comment: You can get the rectangular bounds of a string when measuring, if that is good enough for you layout. but you may still need to go though the text to restrict each drawstring to one page.. But line spacing is really up to your choice/needs.

Comment: @TaW The problem is getting an overall picture of how tall strings will be.  How do I do that short of checking each string??

Comment: I don't think you can. Checking each string is the natural way to go, imo. And, of curse, compared to actual printing it will take no time at all..

Comment: @TaW As far as I can tell the problem is the reported height of the font does not include the space that Windows adds between lines.  I believe the height + that gap is the number I want--but I see no easy way to get it.

Comment: Did you [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx) ?

Comment: @TaW That looks like it might lead to my answer.  I have to head out now so I'll investigate later.